# Why is it not printing asterisks?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to print the "*********" of password matched the condition or it print the else message but instead it's printing the password. What is happening?

```js
class User{
    username
    password

    constructor(username, password){
     this.username = username
     this.password = password
    }
    get password(){
        return this.password.replace(/./g, '*')
    }
    set password(newPassword){
        const passwordRegex = /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}$/
        if(passwordRegex.test(newPassword)){
            this.password = newPassword
        }else{
          console.error("Password must be at least 8 characters long and contain at least one number and one uppercase letter")
        }
    }
}

const user = new User('username', 'myPassword')
console.log(user.password);
```

Comment: What were you expecting `username` and `password` at the top of the class to do? If you delete them you can see that setting `this.password` _in `set password`_ is causing a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Make the stored password have its own property name, distinct from `password`

That way you can access `password` from outside, and interact with the getter and setter functions, without interfering with the real stored password.

```js
class User{
    username
    storedPassword

    constructor(username, password){
     this.username = username
     this.storedPassword = password
    }
    get password(){
        return this.storedPassword.replace(/./g, '*')
    }
    set password(newPassword){
        const passwordRegex = /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}$/
        if(passwordRegex.test(newPassword)){
            this.storedPassword = newPassword
        }else{
          console.error("Password must be at least 8 characters long and contain at least one number and one uppercase letter")
        }
    }
}

const user = new User('username', 'myPassword')
console.log(user.password);
```